# Winforms / WPF Private bytes Memory Leak?

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, memory-leaks, red-gate-ants

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to work on a Winform / WPF project.

It uses multiple projects and classes to build it into a working product.

My problem is, we have noticed that there is a 4-8k per second leak in the memory usage. granted it is a small leak, but it is non-stop continuous 4-8k. Our application runs over night and even for a few days at time. When those few days comes alone, this thing has eaten up more memory than the computer can handle (usually 2-3 gigs) and a force restart on the pc is the only solution. This leak occurs even while nothing is happening except network communications with our host.

After further analysis on the project through ANTS Memory Profiler, we have discovered that the Private bytes data is continuously growing. Is there any way to tell where this private data is being created from? I haven't had much luck tracking this down with ANTS. Steps would help greatly!

Image of the private bytes increasing (~45 minutes):

[image: graph of the private bytes at each snapshot]

Image of the Time line growth (~45 minutes):

[image: timeline of the private byte growth]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'd try a CPU profiler. Probably, where the CPU is spent, there is memory allocated.

Comment: A managed memory profiler is notoriously unhelpful to diagnose unmanaged memory leaks.  Spend some time looking for an environmental factor.  Enable unmanaged debugging and look at the debugger's Debug + Windows + Modules window, make sure that everything you see is something you can account for.  Good way to find the cr*pware that pretends to keep the machine safe and more usable.  Anti-malware first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the private bytes keep increasing, it means you have a memory leak. Try [DebugDiag](http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=40336), it is from MS and free, also a very good tool to tracking memory leak on Windows.

Use this tool is simple, first you create a rule to monitor your process with DebugDiag collection, it will create memory dump according to your rule, you can create the memory dump manually. Then you can use DebugDiag Analysis to analysis the dump, please set the right symbol path before analysis.

This MSDN article [Identify And Prevent Memory Leaks In Managed Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163491.aspx) might help too. This article points our how to find out if the memory leak is a native one or managed one.  If it is a purely .NET manage leak, you can also use [CLR profiler](http://clrprofiler.codeplex.com/) to debug the problem.